# how do I join three tables into one table in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, join

How do I join these tables into one where I can find out which customer had the highest order quantity?

table a
| order ID | customer ID    |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 123| 999|
| 456| 888|

table b
| Order ID | order quantity |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 123| 178|
| 456| 265|

table c
| customer ID | customer name |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 888| bob|
| 999| daniel|

expected result:
| Customer name | order quantity |
| -------- | -------------- |
| bob| 265|
| daniel| 178|

Here's my attempt:

```
select table b. orderquantity, table c. customername
from table b.
left join table a on table a.orderid = table b. orderid
left join table c on table c.customerid = table a. customerid
```

Comment: You don't need the word "table" in there at all.  Beyond that, your syntax looks basically correct.

Comment: Also, use `from table b` without that trailing period.  The dot is only used to separate a table name from a column name.

Answer (score 0):

To find the value with the highest orderquantity (assuming the type is int), you can use the `MAX` function.

The `MAX` function itself cannot be written in `WHERE` clause, so you must use a subquery.

```sql
SELECT b.orderquantity, c.customername
FROM b
LEFT JOIN a ON a.orderid = b.orderid
LEFT JOIN c ON c.customerid = a.customerid
WHERE b.orderquantity = (SELECT MAX(orderquantity) FROM b);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**